# Make element unclickable (click things behind it)

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll, touch

I have a fixed image that overlays a page when the user is in the act of scrolling a touch screen (mobile).

I want to make that image "unclickable" or "inactive" or whatever, so that if a user touches and drags from that image, the page behind it still scrolls as if the image weren't there "blocking" the interaction.

Is this possible? If need be, I could try to provide screen shots exemplifying what I mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Setting CSS -  `pointer-events: none` should remove any mouse interaction with the image. Supported pretty well in all but IE.

[Here's a full list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values) of values `pointer-events` can take.

Comment: Perfect! I had not run across `pointer-events` before, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Dusty Kinda makes sense, you're disabling mouse interactions yet wanting mouse interactions. What is your specific use case? From a UX perspective that seems counter intuitive since the pointer implies the element is clickable. If you throw together a JSFiddle I can have a look.

Comment: @ChrisBrown the cursor changing was a little jostling.  Here's a little bit of what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/cxwvdos0/ Kind of crazy just to disable a button for one second and not have the cursor change. jQuery `unbind` and `bind` I think would have worked if I wanted to convert my anonymous functions. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal Really? What did you find? MDN doesn't say anything about it not working on mobile devices

Answer (score 20):

CSS Pointer Events is what you want to look at. In your case, set pointer-events to "none".
Look at this JSFiddle for an example... http://jsfiddle.net/dppJw/1/

Notice that double clicking on the icon will still say you click the paragraph.

```
div.child {
    ...    
    background: #fff;
    pointer-events: none //This line is the key!
}
```

Comment: Single clicking*, and the code example (clicking the icon) doesn't work for me in FF 68.0.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use JavaScript :

```js
document.getElementById("x").style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="x" />Unclickable Google Link</a>
<br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" id="" />Clickable Google Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is CSS tutorial(the easiest):

```css
#button {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- The element -->
<button id="button">Unclickable!</button>
```