# Disable click using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have to disable link in the image so that the user can not click on that image what can I do ?

code -

```
<a href={fb} target="_blank" onClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
}}>
 <span style={{ fontSize: '17px', color: '#1930f42a' }} >
    <img className='logo' src={Fb} height={28} />
 </span>
</a>
```

Comment: i think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083061/make-element-unclickable-click-things-behind-it

Comment: What have you tried already? It's also odd to attach an `href` ***and*** `onClick` handler to an anchor tag. Can you provide an example of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to prevent redirect when clicking on link

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href={fb} target="_blank" onClick={(e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
}}>
 <span style={{ fontSize: '17px', color: '#1930f42a' }} >
    <img className='logo' src={Fb} height={28} />
 </span>
</a>
```

You need to use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behavior of the link